# Transversality is generic

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, transversality

Let $M$ and $N$ be submanifolds of $\mathbb R^n$. I am trying to prove that for almost every $x\in \mathbb R^n$, $M+x$ and $N$ intersect transversely. Intuitively, transversality is a "generic" condition, so if we slightly change $x$, we can make the intersection transverse. However, I do not know how to make this intuition precise. Can anyone explain?

Comment: Transversality requires that the tangent spaces of the submanifolds  at the intersection point span the tangent space of the ambient space $\mathbb R^n$. Is this the case for two generic linear subspaces of $\mathbb R^n$ of appropriate dimension?

Comment: Are you allowed to quote Sard's theorem?  Try to define a smooth map on $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is critical at exactly those $x$ for which $M+x$ is not transverse to $N$.

Comment: Can you give me a little more detail on how to do this?

Comment: @user15464 I have turned my hint into an answer-hint with more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define a map which is critical exactly when $M+x$ is not transverse to $N$.  Then you can throw Sard's theorem at the problem and conclude that the non-transverse points have measure zero.

Define $f:M\times\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ by $(m,x)\mapsto m + x$.  Define $B = f^{-1}(N)$.  Now let $g$ be the projection of $B$ onto the $\mathbb{R}^n$ coordinate.

The idea here is to fix $N$ and let $f$ capture the motion of $M$ through $\mathbb{R}^n$.  The preimage of $N$ under $f$, what we're calling $B$, we can think of as a family of sets $(M+x)\cap N\subset M$ parametrized by $\mathbb{R}^n$.  You want to verify that for almost every $x$, $(M+x)\pitchfork N$, i.e., at each point $p$ of intersection $(M+x)\cap N$, $T_pM + T_pN = T_p\mathbb{R}^n$.

I'll let you take it from here, unless you'd like me to finish the problem.  The gist of what's left is relating the surjectivity of $dg$ to the transveraslity of $M$ and $N$.

Comment: Can you finish the proof? I appear to be running into a problem since the argument requires that $B$ be a submanifold of $M\times\mathbb R^n$, and for this to be the case I believe we need some sort of transversality hypothesis to begin with.

Comment: @user15464 I'll try to find time to finish it off from my notes (it's a problem in Guillemin/Pollack).